# Sonata Admin - boolean field type, label not displayed

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm creating a Sonata Admin page for an Entity (generated with Symfony CLI).

In this Entity I have 3 textfields and 1 checkbox(boolean). Everthing is well generated except the checkbox. The checkbox is strangly located and there is no label.

In the configureFormFields I defined the checkbox field as it:

```
->add("online",null, array('required' => false, "label" => "My label"))
```

And on the Entity I have:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="online", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
 private $online;
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image: No checkbox label]

Is it a known problem? Have you got any solution?

Comment: I have tried this, but I cannot reproduce your problem. The checkbox (and its label) renders fine in my case. Have you cleared your cache, updated vendors (`composer update`), etc.? Are you running in dev environment with error reporting on? Did you inspect the HTML source code to see if there's anything odd?

Comment: And, of course, did you override any of the Sonata Admin templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I found the solution:

I was using Symfony **2.6.*** when I changed to Symfony **2.3** problem was fixed!

So I look in SonataAdmin GitHub issue to found this working solution:
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2630

At the end I am in Symfony 2.6 with checkbox label.